# VBA Excel cell to SAP GUI error "at 207 ')' expected"

Tags: excel, vba, scripting, sap-gui

I am struggling to get the right information from an Excel sheet via VBA script into SAP.

A single cell works fine and will go into SAP GUI screen but the original Excel sheet contains a cell where the last 4 digits need to be deleted and afterwards combined with another cell and then added to go into SAP GUI screen.

This works fine for me:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP06/ssubTABFRA1:SAPLMGMM:2000/subSUB5:SAPLZMM_GINCOFIELDS:5802/ctxtMARC-PRCTR").text = (objSheet.Cells(6,"P") & (objSheet.Cells(38,"P")).Value)
```

But this one doesn't:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCR_BEWERT:SAPLCTMS:5000/tabsTABSTRIP_CHAR/tabpTAB1/ssubTABSTRIP_CHAR_GR:SAPLCTMS:5100/tblSAPLCTMSCHARS_S/ctxtRCTMS-MWERT[1,1]").text = (objSheet.Cells(40,"F") & (Left((40,"F"), Len(40,"F") - 4)) & (objSheet.Cells(39,"L") & (objSheet.Cells(39,"O").Value)
```

The error message while starting the script means translated:

> ... at 207 ')' expected ...

Thanks in advance for having a look at this and providing help or a hint.

Comment: I think i found the missing ')' but now I get the runtime error: 
Type conflict: '[string: "F"]'
with the following Code:
(objSheet.Cells(40,"F" (Left(40,"F"), Len(40,"F") - 4)) & (objSheet.Cells(39,"L") & (objSheet.Cells(39,"O"))).Value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `Left(40,"F")`: I suspect that what you actually mean is `objSheet.Cells(40, "F")`. Same with your `Len` call, I suspect what you actually want is: `Len(objSheet.Cells(40, "F"))`. So putting that together:

```
Left(objSheet.Cells(40, "F"), Len(objSheet.Cells(40, "F")) - 4) & objSheet.Cells(39, "L") & objSheet.Cells(39, "O")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Zac...thats what I was looking for.
Great!

Comment: If the answer helped, don't forget to accept it. That way it gets taken off the unanswered queue